# Dependency error installing Sails.js globally

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Can't install sails.js on my Ubuntu desktop for some reason. I see the following in the npm log file:

```
Error: no compatible version found: underscore.string@'~2.2.0rc'
```

Any help much appreciated

EDIT:

I've removed nodejs, downloaded and installed the latest version along with npm and now it just hangs at the following:

```
> bson@0.1.8 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
```

EDIT 2:

Actually all I had to is wait 5 minutes to finish installing. That's a long time!!

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume you got nodejs from the chris-lea ppa.

try `sudo npm cache clear`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might have the same problem as me all I had to do is get the latest nodejs from [here](http://nodejs.org/) and install it.